# Is there any application which is create a (fake) incoming SMS from a Google Calendar event?

Tags: notifications, google-calendar-api

That would be a great notification method. Since the Google not sending anymore SMS reminder, and the other portals doing that for charge; That would be nice to have a small application which is create a (fake) incoming SMS from the Google Calendar events (including all days event) in a certain (pre-set) time.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert), Google still sends SMS reminder. However, the are **only available** for G Suite customers. Requests to set SMS reminders for other account types are ignored. If you are a G Suite customer, you may check this [page](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/45351?hl=en) on how to turn on SMS notifications.